# Pointer file error: Unable to parse pointer at: "File path" with git

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, git-lfs

I am trying to merge a branch A into branch B.

But merge failed with error 
`Pointer file error: Unable to parse pointer at: "File path"` for several files in the repository. (`*.meta`, `*.unity` , `*.mat`, `*.json`, `*.prefab`)

I have tried multiple solution that I found on net.

1. Updated source tree(using this) and git lfs to the latest version (2.3.4)
2. Tried command line merge
3. Tried commands `git lfs uninstall` and `git lfs install`.

But none of the above solutions worked for me.

It is unity3d project repository.

Comment: This is likely to be someone else using plain Git instead of Git-LFS: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2260